# Change inheritance strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a class A with some data

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class A {
  @Id
  @Column
  int id;
  @Column
  String name;
}
```

And now I want to change that strategy for a subclass

```
@Entity
public class B extends A {
  @Column
  String extraFieldFromB;
}

@Entity
public class C extends B {
  @Column
  String extraFieldFromC;
}
```

The problem is a simplification of my real problem. I would like to know if I can use a different strategy on class B (ideally JOINED, but SINGLE_TABLE is acceptable). I know the strategy for A was chosen wrong, but now is too much work to change that. I can only attempt to do things right for the descendants of A (which is almost every class in my project).

When I tried including the JOINED inheritance in B, hibernate errors were pointing me that fields from A where missing in the table of C. Is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing inheritance strategy isn't supported by Hibernate. You could try composition instead, e.g. some `AdditionalDetails` entity that is the owner of the relation to your `A` (`B` and `C` could contain back references but the corresponding tables wouldn't store the foreign keys, those are stored in the additional details table).

Comment: JPA does not allow changing the inheritance strategy. You define it for the root entity only